# Browser autocomplete suggestions hides Bootstrap typeahaed suggestions

Tags: autocomplete, typeahead

I have used bootstrap typeahead to create an input field that fetches suggestions from a database with autocomplete ="new-password". Up until recently this worked well, but now in Chrome the browser also makes suggestions and they hide the bootstrap suggestions (see screenshot). How can I get rid of the browser suggestions?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a timestamp to the name so the browser no longer knows what to suggest.

Please let me know if you have a better solution.